# Permutation avoidance function

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, code-review, permutation

It is common for me to see if a permutation of 1,2,...,n, avoids some fixed permutation pattern. For example, the permutation [1,4,2,3,5]
contains the pattern 1,3,2, as the elements [1,4,3] appear in the same relative order.
For example, a function which checks if the input permutation contains
the pattern 213 can be coded easily as this:

```
Is213AvoidingQ[p_List] := !MatchQ[p, {___, a_, ___, b_, ___, c_, ___} /; c > a > b];
```

Now, given a permutation pi, I want to create a function,
which returns true, precisely when the input avoids pi.
The idea I have is to generalize the above code,
and I got the following:

```
IsPermutationAvoidingFunction[pi_List] := 
  Module[{getVar, getBlankVar, ff, n, c, var, pattern, cond},
   getVar[i_] := ToExpression@StringJoin["a", ToString@i];
   getBlankVar[i_] := ToExpression@StringJoin["a", ToString@i, "_"];
   n = Max@pi;
   var = Table[getBlankVar[i], {i, n}];
   pattern = Evaluate[Flatten[{___, Riffle[var, ___], ___}]];
   cond = Table[getVar[Ordering[pi][[n + 1 - i]]], {i, n}];
   cond = Greater @@ cond;
   cond = Condition[pattern, Evaluate@cond];
   ReleaseHold[ff[{p},
      ! Hold[MatchQ][p, cond]
      ] /. ff -> Function]
  ];
```

Now, `IsPermutationAvoidingFunction[{2,1,3}]`
and `Is213AvoidingQ` do the same thing, great!
But can the code above be made nicer? At it is now, it looks horrible.

Answer (score 5):

I think another way of phrasing your permutation avoidance problem is

> *Does there exist no sublist, whose elements has the same ordering as pi?*

which can be straightforwardly implemented using `Ordering`

```
IsPermutationAvoidingFunctionNew[pi_?PermutationListQ]:=
    Function[p,!MemberQ[Ordering /@ Subsets[Ordering@p, {Length @ pi}], pi]]
```

This should behave the same as your function

```
func1=IsPermutationAvoidingFunction[{2,1,4,3}]
func2=IsPermutationAvoidingFunctionNew[{2,1,4,3}]

And@@Table[func1[perm] === func2[perm], {perm,Permutations[Range@8]}]
(* True *)
```

and has approximately the same runtime

```
RepeatedTiming[func1/@Permutations@Range@9;]
RepeatedTiming[func2/@Permutations@Range@9;]
(* {23.5909, Null} *)
(* {23.2453, Null} *)
```

(at least for this example)

Comment: I agree that this brute-force approach is the same, but I wonder if the MatchQ might be quicker sometimes (certainly, one can do some shortcuts, say if i and j are not in the right order, then no need to check any of the {i,j,k} subsets...). But MatchQ is perhaps not this smart...

Comment: FYI, if we use `{5, 3, 1, 4, 2}` as the permutation pattern, then the two functions are not equivalent `And @@ Table[func1[perm] === func2[perm], {perm, Permutations[Range@7]}]` gives `False`. Likely @Per Alexandrsson algorithm is in error?

Comment: The code by Haussdorff has a bug. There is an 'ordering' missing, and should be: IsPermutationAvoidingFunctionNew[pi_?PermutationListQ]:=
    Function@@HoldComplete[p,!MemberQ[Ordering /@ Subsets[Ordering@p, {Length @ pi}], pi]]

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Whoops, thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding *"can the code above be made nicer"*, perhaps:

```
ClearAll[toCondition, avoidsQ]

toCondition = Module[{v = Table[Unique[], Length @ #]}, 
 Condition[Riffle[Pattern[#, _] & /@ v, ___, {1, -1, 2}], #] &[Less @@ Permute[v, #]]]&

avoidsQ[perm_] := Not @* MatchQ[toCondition @ perm];

(* or avoidsQ[perm_] := MatchQ[Except @ toCondition @ perm]; *)
```

***Examples:***

```
toCondition[{2, 1, 3}]
```

> ```
>  {___, $21_, ___, $22_, ___, $23_, ___} /; $22 < $21 < $23
> ```

```
toCondition[{2, 4, 1, 3}]
```

> ```
>  {___, $25_, ___, $26_, ___, $27_, ___, $28_, ___} /; $27 < $25 < $28 < $26
> ```

`avoidsQ` gives the same result as OP's `IsPermutationAvoidingFunction` and is slightly faster:

```
p = {2, 1, 3};

res1 = avoidsQ[p] /@ Permutations[Range @ 8]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.70
> ```

```
res2 = IsPermutationAvoidingFunction[p] /@ Permutations[Range @ 8]; // 
   RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.797
> ```

```
res1 == res2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

For large input lists both `avoidsQ` and `IsPermutationAvoidingFunction` are much faster than `notPermPatternMatch` from MikeY's post and `IsPermutationAvoidingFunctionNew` from Hausdorff's post:

```
SeedRandom[1]
rs = RandomSample @ Range @ 200;
pi = {3, 2, 1, 4};

avoidsQ[pi] @ rs // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
>  {0.034, False}
> ```

```
IsPermutationAvoidingFunction[pi] @ rs // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
>  {0.036, False}
> ```

```
notPermPatternMatch[rs, pi] // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
>  {5.03, False}
> ```

```
IsPermutationAvoidingFunctionNew[pi] @ rs // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
>  {59.8, False}
> ```

Comment: Ah, so there is indeed some value in using the built-in MatchQ then? Interesting!

Comment: Nice! So often I find using patterns slows down algorithms.

Comment: Wow, and even in the case where there aren't any matches it is pretty fast. For example, `avoidsQ[{3, 2, 1, 4}] @ Reverse @ Range @ 200` returns `True` in just 95 seconds

Comment: @MikeY, Hausdorff, I too am surprised. (Perhaps  we shouldn't be since pattern matching is a crucial piece of Mathematica smarts)

Comment: My guess is that these types of patterns are compiled/transformed into some finite state machine or similar, and optimized fairly aggressively (e.g., similar to regex).

Answer (score 2):

Added for posterity, as it's a little slower result than @Hausdorrff's.

The idea was to permute each subset as per $pi$ and see if it is ordered.

```
 makePermAvoidingFunk[pi_List] := 
   Function @@ HoldComplete[perm,Nor@@Map[OrderedQ@#[[pi]] &, Subsets[perm, {Length@pi}]]]
```

EDIT

If the perm is much larger in size than the pattern, then it makes sense to break it up and not create all of the subsets. Here's a function that takes the perm and the pattern.

```
 nppm[perms_, pat_] := ! MemberQ[Ordering /@ perms, pat];
```

and

```
 notPermPatternMatch[perm_?PermutationListQ, pat_?PermutationListQ] := 
    Module[
      {
       lenPat = Length@pat,
       parts,
       partSize = 1000 (* how big of a bite to take each iteration *)
       },

     parts = Partition[Range[Binomial[Length@perm, Length@pat]], UpTo@partSize];
      Catch[
         Scan[If[nppm[Subsets[perm, {lenPat}, {First@#, Last@#}], pat] ==False, Throw[False]] &, parts]; 
         True
        ] (* end catch *)
      ];
```

Test

```
 pi = {3, 2, 1, 4};
 func2 = IsPermutationAvoidingFunctionNew[pi];

 rs = RandomSample@Range@200;
 func2@rs // Timing
 (*  {26.7344, False} *)

 notPermPatternMatch[rs, pi] // Timing
 (*  {3.20313, False}  *)
```